# Let xUnit combine parameters

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

When using xUnit, one can have the same test run multiple times with different data using the InlineData attribute.

```
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("A", 1)]
  [InlineData("B", 2)]
  public void TestAllValues(string x, int y)
```

I want to combine those parameters in all possible combinations. I could write it as follow.

```
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("A", 1)]
  [InlineData("A", 2)]
  [InlineData("A", 3)]
  [InlineData("B", 1)]
  [InlineData("B", 2)]
  [InlineData("B", 3)]
  public void TestAllValues(string x, int y)
```

In my case I need to test a lot more combinations, lets say for each letter of the alphabet and for every number from one to 100. I like to write something like

```
  [Theory]
  [InlineData("A-Z", 1..100)]
  public void TestAllValues(string x, int y)
```

Or any equivalent that does not require 2.600 lines. The example is made up for simplicity, but I really need a lot of cases to be tested.

As a bonus question. Can I reflect the combination in the  name of the Test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that there is something called the `MemberData` attribute.

```
 [Theory]
 [MemberData(nameof(AllCombinations))]        
 public void TestAllValues(string x, int y)
 {
```

Where you can generate all desired combinations.

```
 public static IEnumerable<object[]>AllCombinations{
    get 
    {
        foreach(var c in generateCombinations()){
           yield return new object [] { c.Letter, c.Number}
        }
    }
```